# MassTransit, using UseMessageScheduler on different virtual host

Tags: masstransit

Is it possible to configure UseMessageScheduler for using different virtual host than its Bus?

I faced "The host was not found for the specified address" while trying to achieve this.

Here is my Bus configuration:

```
_myBus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
{
    var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/MyVirtualHostName"), h =>
    {
        h.Username("guest");
        h.Password("guest");
    });

    sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "MySaga", ep =>
    {
        var machine = new MyStateMachine();
        ep.StateMachineSaga(machine, _sagaRepository);

        sbc.UseMessageScheduler(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/Quartz"));
    });
});
```

Also I checked that MassTransit.QuartzService is running and consuming "rabbitmq://localhost/Quartz".

When I use scheduling on same virtual host, it works fine. To be more clear, My intent is to have different application with different virtual host using same QuartzService.

I use:
MT 5.1.4
Automatonymous 5.1.3
MassTransit.Quartz 5.1.4

Any help really appreciated :)

Comment: Why? Complexity? You can, if you define both hosts for the bus, at least it should work. I've honestly never tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @chris-patterson comment, I solved this problem by adding another host inside my bus. here is my config:

```
_myBus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
 {
     var quartzHost = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
     {
        h.Username("guest");
        h.Password("guest");
     });

     var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/MyVirtualHostName"), h =>
     {
        h.Username("guest");
        h.Password("guest");
     });

     sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "MySaga", ep =>
     {
         var machine = new MyStateMachine();
         ep.StateMachineSaga(machine, _sagaRepository);

         sbc.UseMessageScheduler(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/Quartz"));
     });
});
```